# Do 64 Bit architectures memory addresses still hold 1 byte

Tags: c, memory, 32bit-64bit

In a 32 bit machine, if you copied an int p, it would copy 4 bytes of information, which would be addressed at 0xbeefbeef, 0xbeefbef0, 0xbeefbef1, 0xbeefbef2 respectively.

Is this the same with 64 bit? Or does it store 2 bytes at a single address?

Comment: If you have 64 bits address bus, why should anyone combine 2 bytes to 1 memory location? There are architectures around which have 2 bytes per address but that does not depend on 64 or 32 bits.

Comment: Honestly the question seems silly in hindsight. Its a great point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the architecture. On most "normal" 64-bit systems (e.g. arm64, x86_64, etc.) memory is "[byte addressed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing)," so each memory address refers to *one* byte (so it's the same as your 32-bit example).

There are systems out there which are *not* byte addressed, and this can included 64-bit architectures. For example, [DSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processor)s are a classic example of systems where `char` can be 32-bits (or more) and an individual byte (or rather, octet) is not addressable.

Comment: Why downvoting this answer?

Comment: Can we really say that those systems are not byte addressed? I.e. in C standard, for example, "char" is identical to "byte", regardless of `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: @Ruslan: That's why I clarified "*or rather, **octet***". Usually when someone says "byte" they really mean "octet". If a system's byte is the same size as a word, then the machine would probably be called "word addressed" instead of "byte addressed," even though from the C standard's perspective it is still technically byte addressed (but certainly not octet addressed, so I wouldn't be at all surprised if most people said the machine was not byte addressed, using the colloquial "byte == octet" meaning of the word).

Answer (score 2):

On a amd64 architecture (also called x86_64 and x64, which is the most common 64-bit architecture), each addressable unit still refers to one byte of memory (8-bits).

Additionally, an `int` still usually contains 4 bytes of memory (32-bits), though this *can* vary from compiler to compiler (as it also does on 32-bit systems).

What will be different is the size of a pointer. On a 32-bit system, pointers are normally 32-bits, but are 64-bits on a 64-bit system (8 bytes). This will allow the computer to access *more* bytes of memory, but each byte is still 8-bits long.

Comment: The question was not related to size of int or size of pointer. It was about size of addressable memory location.

Comment: And the pointers can be 32-bit even in a 64-bit application, see [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI).